# Assigning optarg to an int in C

Tags: c, unix, casting, int

I am trying to assign an optarg value to an int, but the compiler gives me the following warning:

```
warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
```

I have tried casting optarg as int before the assignment

```
n = (int) optarg;
```

but still get a warning:

```
warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
```

I am not sure what needs to be done before I can simply assign the optarg to an integer, then print it (for now).

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char c;
  int n;

  while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "m:")) != -1) {
    switch (c) {
    case 'm':
      n = optarg;
      break;
    }
  }

  printf("%d\n", n);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: is this 64 bit Linux ? if so, change int to long

Comment: @Mellowcandle: not necessarily. Perhaps the author know that `n` is a tiny integer...

Comment: Hint specially useful to beginner: compile with `gcc -Wall -g` and improve your program till no warnings are given. Then learn how to use the `gdb` debugger.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The option string is *always* a string.

If you want an integer, you need to use a conversion function, like [atoi(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atoi.3.html)

So you should at least code

```
n = atoi(optarg);
```

Beware, `optarg` could be `NULL` and could certainly be a non-number. You might use [strtol(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html) which may set the ending character which you would check.

So a more serious approach could be

```
case 'm':
  {
     char* endp = NULL;
     long l = -1;
     if (!optarg ||  ((l=strtol(optarg, 0, &endp)),(endp && *endp)))
       { fprintf(stderr, "invalid m option %s - expecting a number\n", 
                 optarg?optarg:"");
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       };
      // you could add more checks on l here...
      n = (int) l;
     break;
  }
  n = optarg;
  break;
```

<sup>Notice the assignment to `l` as expression and the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) inside the `if` test.</sup>

BTW, GNU Libc also have [argp](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argp.html) functions (and also [getopt_long](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt-Long-Options.html) - but `argp` functions are more powerful), which you may find more convenient. Several frameworks (notably Gtk and Qt) have also program argument passing functionalities.

If you are doing a serious program please make it accept the `--help` option, and if possible the `--version` one. It is really convenient, and I hate the few programs which don't accept them. See what [GNU standards](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#Command_002dLine-Interfaces) say.

Comment: My man pages say that strtol accepts a base as the last parameter. Which might mean that the code segment has a bug?
`long int strtol(const char *nptr, char **endptr, int base);`

Answer (score 5):

`optarg` is a pointer to a string - if you want to convert that to an integer, the simplest way is with `atoi`:

```
case 'm':
    n = atoi(optarg);
    break;
```