# linux application remote debugging without gdb

Tags: c, linux

I wrote a linux program as below:

```
int g_para1 = 10;
int g_para2 = 11;

void SetPara(int para1, int para2)
{
    g_para1 = para1;
    g_para2 = para2;
}

void DumpPara()
{
    printf("g_para1 = %d, g_para2 = %d\n", g_para1,g_para2);

}

void init()
{
    int pid;

    if(pid = fork())
        exit(0); 
    else if(pid < 0)
        exit(1);

    setsid();

    if(pid = fork())
        exit(0);  
    else if(pid < 0) 
        exit(1);   

    return;
}

int main()
{   
    signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);

    init();
    while(1)
    {   
        DumpPara();
        sleep(10);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And then compile and run it in the shell

```
gcc -o test test.c
./test
```

it will show the print "g_para1 = 10, g_para2 = 11" every 10 seconds.

My question is:
If I execute "SetPara 20, 30"  in the shell, i want the print shows "g_para1 = 20, g_para2 = 30".
What should i do to make it work?

If I do nothing, it will show

```
SetPara 20,30
SetPara: command not found
```

Comment: You should take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking a question

Comment: What kind of application is it? Your question is very unclear... And how do you install it and start it at the remote site? What OS is running remotely? Please **improve your question** by editing it appropriately.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch   Thanks ~  Question improved.

Comment: Don't call your binary `test` since `test` is a shell builtin or `/usr/bin/test`

Comment: On failure of most functions (in particular of the `fork` syscall) you should report the `errno` using e.g. `perror`

Answer (score 0):

First, an application (in C, compiled with debug info, e.g. with `gcc -Wall -g`) can be remotely debugged. If you have `ssh` available, you simply debug using `gdb` thru a terminal connection via `ssh`. Otherwise, read the [documentation of GDB](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/index.html), it has a chapter on [remote debugging](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/Remote-Debugging.html#Remote-Debugging).

Then, it looks like you wish to embed your application into a scripting language interpreter. Then try [lua](http://www.lua.org/), or [GNU guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/), or perhaps even [python](http://python.org/) or [ocaml](http://caml.inria.fr/ocaml/index.en.html). Notice that embedding your application inside an interpreter (or symetrically, putting an interpreter inside your application) is a heavy architectural decision and has major impacts on its design.

BTW, some Unix shells can be extended thru [plugins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_%28computing%29), e.g. [zsh](http://zsh.org/) (with [modules](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#Zsh-Modules)...). Plugins use [dynamic loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading) facilities like [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) (you might consider using them in your application).

But an ordinary shell can only start external programs using [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) & [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)

BTW, you might consider making your application behave as a Web server by using some [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) server library inside it, e.g. [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/). You could also consider [remote procedure call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) techniques, e.g. [JSON RPC](http://jsonrpc.org/)

Read also [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

As for your improved question, just define a convention in `main` arguments: you could want that if you invoke your program with arguments `--setpara 23 45` it will call `SetPara(23,45)` e.g. with code like:

```
  int main (int argc, char**argv) {
    if (argc>3 && !strcmp[argv[1], "--setpara")) {
        int x = atoi(argv[2]);
        int y = atoi(argv[3]);
        SetPara (x,y);
    }
```

but you should do serious arguments passing e.g. with [getopt_long](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt-Long-Options.html) (and accept `--help` & `--version`). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18877449/841108) and [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16573351/841108).

If you want `SetPara` to be called elsewhere in your code, the arguments to  `main` should trigger other behavior (e.g. initializing global data, initializing an embedded interpreter, etc.).

Notice that each [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) has its own [address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space) in [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory). See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26849260/841108).

<sup>PS: your question is very unclear; I tried to give various ways of approaching your issues, which I am mostly guessing. You should study -for inspiration at least- the source code of some existing free software related to your goals.</sup>

Comment: Hi @Basile Starynkevitch , your answer is very useful.But if I don't want to change the paras when program start to run. I want to change them at runtime. When the program is running, i want to change `g_para1` and `g_para2` via `SetPara x, y`(x, y can be any number) rather than main arguments. What should i do?

Comment: `SetPara x, y` wants to be executed in the shell.